# Creating complex WPF-Window in Background

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, background

I have a very complex Window created with WPF.

Since it takes very long time to load (about 10s), I want to create the window in the background after startup of the application.

My Shell contains one button where this window will be used, when the User clicks on it. The idea is to load the application and this button is disabled. After loading, my complex will be created in the background. When the window is created, I can enable this button and the user can use it.

But it is very important, that the Application does not block, while the window will be created on the background. The user should be able to use other modules in this time.

Does somebody know a way to reach my goal?

Perhaps someone knows, if there are more possibilities to reach this goal in the next .NET-Framework 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create window in background thread. Things you need to pay attention to are:

1. Thread must be STA and should be background thread so it will be terminated if main application thread is terminated.
2. You must keep that background thread alive or you will loose your window.
3. When referencing other GUI elements you should use Dispatcher.Invoke or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke if that GUI element is from another thread.

Here's the example for creating window in background thread:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Window windowInAnotherThread = new Window();
            windowInAnotherThread.Show();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }) { IsBackground = true };
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Note that you can not create the actual window in the `BackgroundWorker`. The window needs to be created on the UI thread. But you can load all necessary data in the `BackgroundWorker` and use that data from the form once it is loaded.